# How to make relation from SQL Server tables directly to Active Directory data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, active-directory

We build applications for a company where the users come indirectly from the company's Active Directory. That is, we still keep local users tables to authenticate and make relations in the database for their authorization information, and the tables sync from Active Directory every hour.

This one hour delay recently caused some serious problems for us and forced us to directly use Active Directory data. The problem is we need each user's records to relate to our tables and Active Directory does not have such a feature by itself.

We need to copy AD data to Database because we are making use of each column. For example, user position or user office branch or user current state and so on.

Actually the most important part is user's changes: when a user account is revoked, disabled, or promoted. If we just get user name and apply Authentication & Authorization rules based on that when they first login, then how we are supposed to be sensitive on user changes during the session?

In fact, we are looking for a way to set aside `sync` procedure and use directly Active Directory Data, but in the end , we need to have user records to make relation to them for our Authorization tables

Comment: It's unclear why you're copying AD data into the SQL database or using those for authentication. I think you're approaching this the wrong way round. Normally it would be your _application_ which uses AD to authenticate the user (e.g. using Windows Authentication in ASP.NET, for example). Then, after authentication, you can simply pass the username to SQL Server (in a query) retrieve the relevant authorisation information for the application's features etc.

Comment: question was updated

Comment: It's fine to copy the data like office location etc if you need it for information, or for authorisation purposes. But like I said, you should not be using the SQL data for authentication. The application should be talking to AD directly for that in 99% of cases. But as the answer below says, if that's too big a change to make, you can have a) a process to override the sync, or fast-delete a specific user account, and b) have real-life business processes such that the person should not have time to do any more accessing of applications once they have been informed it's been disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Active Directory is intended to work with multiple domain controllers, where each domain controller replicates changes to the others. This replication process is **NOT INSTANTANEOUS!**  That is, even within Active Directory itself, there can be a delay between when a change is made and when that change shows up everywhere.

Therefore, ultimately the business has to learn that these changes take a little bit of time to propagate. This is really more of a procedural issue than a technology issue. Even if you have a situation where an a sensitively employee needs to be immediately terminated, that's a PEOPLE problem. Yes, you revoke their access, but you also have an HR person and the manager there with the employee to remove them from the premises. Now in a pandemic, with remote work, you engage them over the phone, and have a separate way in the application to revoke access force a new sync (authorization) operation.

Comment: You mean our sync process should be removed?

Comment: No, it should not be removed. Instead, you need a a button somewhere so an admin can force it to run NOW if they need to.